# Steps for Signing the certificate (CA signed certificate)

Tags: integration

We are using Salesforce CA signed certificate. We would like to know the steps for signing the certificate which needs to done at the external system. Once signed can be uploaded in Salesforce.

Comment: CA is an identity suite or security certificate provider. You can find them on the web at this URL which includes links for live chat and phone contact info: http://www.ca.com/us/securecenter/ca-identity-suite.aspx?intcmp=featuredprod_CA+Identity+Suite.

Answer (score 4):

The steps for getting a certificate signed by a Certificate Authority are these:

> 1. From Setup, click Security Controls | Certificate and Key Management, click the name of the certificate, then click Download Certificate Signing Request.
> 2. Send the certificate request to the certificate authority of your choice.
> 3. After the certificate authority sends back the signed certificate, from Setup, click Security Controls | Certificate and Key Management, click the name of the certificate, then click Upload Signed Certificate.
> 4. Click Browse to locate the CA-signed certificate. The CA-signed certificate must match the certificate created in Salesforce. If you try to upload a different CA-signed certificate, the upload fails.
> 5. Click Save to finish the upload process. Click Cancel at any time to not upload the certificate.

Found in this Salesforce help document: [Uploading Certificate Authority (CA)-Signed Certificates](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_keys_uploading_signed_cert.htm&language=en_US)

---

Essentially, you take the CSR file you've downloaded from Salesforce and have it signed by the company of your choosing and then return to Salesforce and upload the certificate generated by your provider.

Your certificate provider's website will have instructions on how to create a certificate.

Comment: is it possible to use openssl to sign this certificate?

Comment: after that i must update all Service Provider with this update certificate?